# How can I edit a matrix recursively given certain conditions?

Tags: matlab

```
grid = [[5 3 0 0 7 0 0 0 0];[6 0 0 1 9 5 0 0 0];[0 9 8 0 0 0 0 6 0];[8 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 3];[4 0 0 8 0 3 0 0 1];[7 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 6];[0 6 0 0 0 0 2 8 0];[0 0 0 4 1 9 0 0 5];[0 0 0 0 8 0 0 7 9]];

function ov = possibility(grid,x,y,n)
ov = true;
for i = 1:9
    if (grid(x,i) | grid(i,y)) == n
        ov = false;
        return
    end
end

xO = floor((x-1)/3)*3;
yO = floor((y-1)/3)*3;

for m = 1:3
    for k = 1:3
        if grid(xO + m, yO + k) == n
            ov = false;
            return
        end
    end
end
end

function solve(grid)
for x = 1:9
    for y = 1:9
        if grid(x,y) == 0
            for n = 1:9
                if possibility(grid,x,y,n)
                    grid(x,y) = n;
                    solve(grid)
                else
                    grid(x,y) = 0;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

Just a disclaimer, this code is not my original work, I'm only trying to figure out recursion because it's always been an odd concept to me. This is from the youtube video https://youtu.be/G_UYXzGuqvM where the program was written in python.

I don't quite understand how to systematically go back through the solve function and allow the code to decide which 'squares' it needs to change, because the way I see it: If `grid(x,y)` were to be 0, and then set to the first possible option, but that option was wrong, the code would never be able to find a solution for the puzzle. I don't get how it would determine to go back and change the incorrect choice to the next available choice which also may or may not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and this is my solution, thanks for all the feedback guys :)

```
function Sudoku_Solver()
clear; close; clc

% manually input sudoku puzzle
gridGrid = [5 3 0 0 7 0 0 0 0;6 0 0 1 9 5 0 0 0;0 9 8 0 0 0 0 6 0;8 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 3;4 0 0 8 0 3 0 0 1;7 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 6;0 6 0 0 0 0 2 8 0;0 0 0 4 1 9 0 0 5;0 0 0 0 8 0 0 7 9];

%{
establishes possibility vector for each index, starts with all possible
solutions 1-9 and removes the non-working ones
%}
gridCell = cellfun(@double, mat2cell(repmat(1:9,9,9),ones(1,9),9*ones(1,9)),'UniformOutput',false);

% used to check common 3x3 grid
squareCheck = repelem(reshape(1:9,3,3)',3,3);

solve()

    function solve()
        % intialize a for loop for indices by row and column
        for x = 1:9
            for y = 1:9
                % Check that the current index is established or not
                if gridGrid(x,y) == 0
                    % if the index is not established check possibilities
                    for n = 1:9
                        possible(x,y,n)
                    end
                    % Check that the possibility is not a singular value
                    if size(gridCell{x,y},2) == 1
                        % if a singular value then establish the index
                        gridGrid(x,y) = gridCell{x,y};
                        % call function with newly established index
                        solve()
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    % establish function to check the integrity of options 1-9 per index
    function possible(deltaX,deltaY,n)
        % initialize a for loop to check row/column
        for deltak = 1:9
            % Check entire row and column of index that we are checking
            if gridGrid(deltaX,deltak) == n || gridGrid(deltak,deltaY) == n
                %{ 
                if any value in the row/column is n that means it is not
                an option and we remove it from the list 
                %}
                gridCell{deltaX,deltaY} = gridCell{deltaX,deltaY}(gridCell{deltaX,deltaY} ~= n);
            end

            %{
            intialize a for loop to check the 3x3 grid that the index
            belongs to
            %}
            for deltai = 1:9
                for deltaj = 1:9
                    % check indices that share a common 3x3 grid
                    if squareCheck(deltai,deltaj) == squareCheck(deltaX,deltaY)
                        if gridGrid(deltai,deltaj) == n
                            % remove any values that are not an option
                            gridCell{deltaX,deltaY} = gridCell{deltaX,deltaY}(gridCell{deltaX,deltaY} ~= n);
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

% print solution to command window
gridGrid

end
```